# Asymmetric KMS Key with Google DLP API

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

Can I use Asymmetric Keys generated in KMS for encrypting and decrypting data through Google DLP APIs ?
https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/creating-asymmetric-keys

Comment: I am unable to access the links provided. Can you please share the estimated timelines for when this would be available?

Comment: Deleted first comment due to unable to edit. No specific timeline when this will be available. You may raise it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches) (new link). Tried the link on my other devise and I can see it. Just find your select feature or feel free to create feature request on the given link.